# How can I do t.test when I don't have a null value?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

I have a dataset containing 20,000 records of home sales. I'm asked

> Choose a numerical variable from your dataset. 1. Calculate a 98% confidence interval for the mean of this variable.

I chose the price and I want to find a 98% confidence interval of the mean. 
It's what I did

```
mu = mean(hs$price)
cat("Mean of population:", mu, "\n")
sample_price = sample(hs$price, 200)

xbar = mean(sample_price)
cat("Mean of sample:", xbar, "\n\n")

t.test(sample_price, conf.level = 0.98, mu=?????)
```

In the code above, what should I put for the `mu` in the `t.test`? Should I put the mean of population? A guess around it? Nothing? zero?
Then what would be the difference if I leave the parameter (I guess the default is zero) or if I put the mean of population?

If i provide no value for `mu` I have:

```
 One Sample t-test

data:  sample_price
t = 25.138, df = 199, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
98 percent confidence interval:
 491719.9 592909.1
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 542314.5
```

If I put the `mu = mu` then I have:

```
One Sample t-test

data:  sample_price
t = 0.1032, df = 199, p-value = 0.9179
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 540088.1
98 percent confidence interval:
 491719.9 592909.1
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 542314.5
```

The confidence interval is the same, however the `t score` is different. Which one is correct? What is the interpretation of each!

Comment: Could you explain why you want to calculate a confidence interval if you have the total population available?

Comment: @COOLSerdash It's a question of a project with a given dataset. The exact phrasing is `Choose a numerical variable from your dataset.
1. Calculate a 98% confidence interval for the mean of this variable.`

Comment: Thanks. You may want to edit your question and add this information. Also, please add the `self-study` tag as these questions are treated a bit differently here. Also I'm pretty sure that the data in the first and second t-test are different. I suspect that you re-ran the code so that a different sample was drawn from the population. If you supply the exact same data, the value of `mu` does not matter for the calculation of the confidence interval. You can also set a seed with `set.seed()` to make the calculations reproducible.

Comment: @COOLSerdash I did, you're right the confidence interval for both is similar if I don't change the sample set. However, `t score` is different. Could one explain why is this so?

Comment: The first test has a different null hypothesis than the second. Specifically, the first has $\mathrm{H}_0: \mu_{0} = 0$ whereas the second one has $\mathrm{H}_0: \mu_{0} = 540088.1$. The $t$-statistic is calculated as $t = (\bar{x}-\mu_{0})/\mathrm{SE}_{\bar{x}}$. So the $t$-statistic depends on the hypothesized population mean `mu`.

Comment: @COOLSerdash so the question remains what I should  provide

Comment: Your question is solely about the confidence interval for which `mu` is irrelevant. So you can provide any number you wish.

Comment: @COOLSerdash cool!!

Comment: @COOLSerdash, if I set mu to xbar, I have p-value = 1, but it says `alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 536420`. I'm curious in which value of `mu` it fail to reject H0